# Crystal Reports issue with Dynamic images from a web service

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with two dynamic images defined by database fields.

One is a location on our intranet :
ex: \<folder>\image.JPG

the second is being pulled from a web service :
https:////TraverseImage.ashx?parcel=312531800000010860&card=1

I followed this excellent walkthrough :
http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/

which suggests "set the formula’s text to the name of the formula or parameter field that will contain the image’s URL"

during design time both images display perfectly.  When running the report or when changing parameters, the first one from the hard drive works perfectly, but the second one from the web service does not update.  The only way to update it is to delete the image, and start over.  I have put a hyperlink on the one from the webservice, and it correctly links to the image I want to display.

I am needing this to stay as a native .rpt and not embedded with VS.

I appreciate any suggestions, or comments.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal dynamic image paths don't support https. Don't blame me; I'm just the messenger.

But you can solve this by using one of the 3rd-party UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).
One of these UFLs allows you to use the graphic location expression for the image in Crystal to on-the-fly download an image from a given url, save it to a local file, and return the path to that file.

As added advantage, it can also resize the image to avoid a known memory consumption issue when Crystal is forced to resize images.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it.  I now know what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path http or https?
If https you can use a UFL to solve this.

Comment: it is an HTTPS, but I am unsure what you mean.